# How to diagnose emacs hanging and 100% cpu on startup?

Tags: debugging, start-up, frozen-emacs

How can I diagnose this issue?

I've tried using strace and I see the following that seems to be stuck in a loop:

```
recvfrom(5, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 567516, 0, NULL, NULL) = 567516
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 567516
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
brk(0x39f4000)                          = 0x39f4000
brk(0x3873000)                          = 0x3873000
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base=".\0\2\0\273\2\340\3-\0\22\0\274\2\340\0039\0-a-misc-cinzel"..., iov_len=88}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 88
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\0\330\tO\0\3\0\377\377\0\0\0\0\20\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\23\0\23\0\20\0"..., iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 4096
brk(0x3934000)                          = 0x3934000
recvfrom(5, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\v\0\v\0\20\0\5\0{*\0\0\t\0\t\0\20\0\5\0P$"..., 782684, 0, NULL, NULL) = 782684
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 782684
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
brk(0x39f4000)                          = 0x39f4000
brk(0x3873000)                          = 0x3873000
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base=".\0\2\0\274\2\340\3-\0\24\0\275\2\340\3D\0-a-misc-cinzel"..., iov_len=96}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 96
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\0\333\tO\0\3\0\372\377\0\0\0\0\20\0\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\26\0\26\0\20\0"..., iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 4096
brk(0x3934000)                          = 0x3934000
recvfrom(5, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\7\0\7\0\20\0\6\0\375\34\1\0\v\0\v\0\20\0\6\0{*"..., 782684, 0, NULL, NULL) = 782684
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 782684
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
brk(0x39f4000)                          = 0x39f4000
brk(0x3873000)                          = 0x3873000
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base=".\0\2\0\275\2\340\3-\0\23\0\276\2\340\3=\0-a-misc-cinzel"..., iov_len=92}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 92
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1strace: Process 12237 detached
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do will be to bisect your user-configuration by commenting stuff out, saving and restarting Emacs until the problem goes away.  Or, build Emacs from source and launch Emacs under GDB to get a meaningful backtrace.  Of course, you want to try it with zero configuration to make sure the stock Emacs is good.

Comment: What @lawlist said. The first thing to do is see if you have the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). If so, then please report an Emacs bug using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, the problem is caused by your init file: bisect to find it.

Comment: Which operating system? Does it occur when starting Emacs with -Q?

Comment: Arch Linux. It did not hang running in via `emacs -nw`. I can't try `-Q` as the issue is no longer present. I think it was caused due to some external system package - as when I updated the issue went away.